# Why does java make us write more code?

Tags: java, date

Why does java make us write more code?
e.g:

```
long time = 1509694664442L;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getTime());
c.getTime().setTime(time); // doesn't update the calendar's time!
System.out.println(c.getTime());
// but this does
Date d = c.getTime();
d.setTime(time);
c.setTime(d);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Fri Jun 22 16:30:06 BRT 2018
Fri Jun 22 16:30:06 BRT 2018
Fri Nov 03 04:37:44 BRT 2017
```

Can someone explain why this happens since calendar.getTime() doesn't return a new instance of java.util.Date?

Comment: please avoid to use both of them Calendar or Date, instead its better to use [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Comment: The Date has no reference to the Calendar so changing the Date doesn't change the Calendar.

Comment: *"[`calendar.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) doesn't return a new instance of `java.util.Date`"* Why on earth would you think that? Of course it returns a new instance every time.

Comment: That's weird! returning a reference would save memory...

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific with the question title. As is, it doesnt fit the accepted answer. Also: "more code than normal" compared to what? Java is a high level language. Not the highest, but in the grand scheme of things probably more concise than 95% of all languages. Python is more abstract than Java, but Java is leaps and bounds more concise than Assembly.

Comment: @Derick Want to guess how many cycles it takes to create a new date object? That's why optimisation should only be done after a whole lot of profiling.

Comment: As commented by Ole V.V., the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does java make us write more code than the normal?

Because you are using the old and outdated date and time classes. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, allows not only terser but also clearer code:

```
long time = 1_509_694_664_442L;
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time);
System.out.println(i);
```

Or, since you asked for brevity:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_509_694_664_442L ).toString()
```

Output:

> 2017-11-03T07:37:44.442Z

For something more human readable (for some of us :-)

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Recife");
Locale brazil = Locale.forLanguageTag("pt-BR");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL)
    .withLocale(brazil);
String formatted = i.atZone(zone).format(formatter);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

> sexta-feira, 3 de novembro de 2017 04:37:44 Horário Padrão de Brasília

### Calendar.getTime()

> …since calendar.getTime() doesn't return a new instance of java.util.Date?

It does exactly that. Here’s the implementation in JDK 10:

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 7):

`Calendar.getTime()` returns a new `Date` instance, so trying to change the value on the returned object is futile, it has no effect on the `Calendar` instance.

Take a look at the source:

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

This clearly shows that changing anything on the returned date doesn't change the calendar object itself.

You could make the change, then call `calendar.setTime` with the modified date to go around this.